Climatzones with no axis tilt (0°)
so im figuring out, where to locate my climate zones.
I create a moon in and orbit around an Gas Giant, that orbits an Blue Giant Star.
My moon is twice as big as earth and has 9 Continents. Each hemisphere has 5 Circulation Cells - caused by its size. The moon rotates around itself - so there is night and day.
But there are no seasons caused by no axis tilt.
Every Climate Model functions with seasonal humidity effects - obviously, but i couldnt figure out, how to adapt this on my moon.
I already have all the Maps and stuff to define climates
Pls help me, im so clueless





If this moon is tidally heated, it won't have normal climate zones.

How did your giant moon not lose all its atmosphere to your gas giant?

@MontyWild, the moon is mainly heated by its star
Caused by the extreme heats of an blue Giant, the heat of tidal heat could be ignored i guess

@FrançoisJurain; well i never thougt about it, but that is an other problem xD

Also, if this world orbits a blue star, it's not likely to have had time for life to evolve upon it.  Blue stars tend to become giants on a timescale of only a few millions of years.

@MontyWild, yes im aware of that, this problem is solved by "magic" haha, but everything else i want to be more scientifically accurate

Blue giants will also produce a punishing amount of atmosphere-stripping ultraviolet radiation. Honestly, if you're magicking away the problem of either stellar lifetime or evolution of life, and you're magicking away the issue of germicidal light from the star, your reader will already be relaxed about the realism of your setting and won't might innaccuracies in your biome layout.

There are also issues with tidal locking (it'll probably happen, unless the gas giant it is orbiting is actually a brown dwarf and probably too far away to look interesting), and either gravity or mineral composition problems for your super-earth. Oh, and you haven't supplied any keys for your maps, or orbital parameters for your moon and gas giant. Honestly, it'll be much simpler if you just go for something that looks fine. Realistically, no-one is going to argue with you, except the one guy on here who can't suspend his disbelief, but there's only one of him so you don't have to care.

You will only have the following (Köppen) climate zones, assuming any other external heating factors are not too significant:

First of all, I am assuming the moon’s axial tilt is zero relative to the star.
All other climate zones are definitionally impossible because they require seasonal variation to occur.
Your equatorial regions will be very hot and humid, all the time. You will also have large desert belts bordered by thin semi-arid and oceanic areas. Poleward, you will have tundra and finally ice-cap. The coverage of the ice-cap will depend on your average surface temperature and pressure.
Either way, the poles should be very cold and the equator very hot as the zero axial tilt will force winds to remain driven entirely by the Coriolis effect; staying at the same latitudes without seasonal variation. High mountains should still produce rain-shadows though.
This post might interest you if you want a better idea of what your map might look like:
https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2022/08/climate-explorations-obliquity.html
